# Kahan summation and relative errors; or real life war stories of "getting the wrong result instead of the correct one"

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I am interested in "war stories" like this one:

1. I wrote a program involving the sum of floating point numbers but I did not use the Kahan summation.
2. The sum was `bad_sum` and the program gave me a wrong result.
3. A colleague of mine, more versed than me in numerical analysis, had a look at the code and suggested me to use the Kahan summation, the sum is now `good_sum` and the program gives me the correct result.

I am interested in real-life production-code, not in code samples "artificially" created in order to explain the Kahan summation algorithm.

In particular what was the relative error `(bad_sum-good_sum)/good_sum` for your application?

Up to now I have no similar story to tell. Maybe I will make some tests (running my program on an input data set, logging the program results and the sums with and without Kahan, estimate the relative error).

Comment: I would really appreciate comments from the downvoters in order to improve the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think that this question just isn't a good fit for SO.  It's too vague for there to be a "correct" answer.  You might have better luck on programmers.stackexchange.